# Zend Framework: whats the difference between / and # Rest API calls?

Tags: zend-framework, rest, controller

I have a site which runs under zend framework. 
Whats the difference between the following calls in terms of controller actions: http://localhost/home/password and http://localhost/home#password? Both works, but the results are slightly different: one output includes some UI elements while another one doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. they are not the same.

In http://localhost/home/password `home` is controller and `password` is action.

In http://localhost/home#password `home` is controller and `index` is action and `#password` is page bookmark which is not accessible through php (zend framework) at all.

Comment: Hmmm... how the password action is executed then in the 2nd case?

Comment: i suppose that u have redirected index action to password action.